# html bootstrap image header does not follow header size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am currently new to web design and I am having a problem with my design.

I am trying to add an image header on the top left of my header but the problem is when I add the image it does not follow the header size but follows it's original image size instead.

I want it to auto-fit the header size. but every time I adjust its height, it overlaps the header or when I add padding to it the image suddenly re sizes to a smaller image.

What seems to be the problem?

This is what it looks like right now:

http://postimg.org/image/6djteoy6l/

A snippet of my html file:

```
 <a class="main-title navbar-brand" href="home.html"><img src="iservice.jpg" id="iLogo"/> </a>
```

a snippet of my css file:

```
#iLogo{
height: 50px;
width: 200px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Could paste your css code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set height to your header as image has. Or give exact example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6djteoy6l/ updated it and did as you've said. But still not quite what I wanted. I wanted it to auto-fit the header size. but everytime I adjust it's height it overlaps the header or when I add padding to it the image suddenly resizes to a smaller image. Will update posted code in my question

Comment: It is really hard to understand the problem without full example.. Problem can be in your header or image positioning(try set position:relative if it is exactly in your header block)